# Jira Widget on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, jira

Can anyone help me on how can I embed jira widget on sharepoint modern page. I am able to embed the below script in classic sharepoint site. Also I can use this code in an html page which workd fine. Below is how it should look.

[image: How it should look]

[image]

Comment: can you paste an example of the Jira widget's code here? how does it look like?

Comment: <script data-jsd-embedded data-key="xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" data-base-url="https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com" src="https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com/assets/embed.js"></script>